# Formating a final String HEADING_FMT_STR

Tags: java

So I have this code

```java
public class CarInventoryReport
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      final String HEADING_FMT_STR = "%-25s%13s%13s%13s\n";
      final String DATA_FMT_STR =  "%-25s%13d%13.0f%13.0f\n";
      String item1 = "Mazda RX-8";
      int qty1 = 10;
      double price1 = 27999.99;
      String item2 = "MINI Cooper";
      int qty2 = 100;
      double price2 = 23000.25;

      System.out.printf(HEADING_FMT_STR,
         "Item", "Quantity", "Price", "Value");
      System.out.printf(HEADING_FMT_STR,
         "-----", "-------", "------", "------");
      System.out.printf(DATA_FMT_STR,item1,qty1,price1,qty1*price1);
      System.out.printf(DATA_FMT_STR,item2,qty2,price2,qty2*price2);
  } // end main
} // end class CarInventoryReport
```

Output:

```
Item                          Quantity        Price        Value
-----                          -------       ------       ------
Mazda RX-8                          10        28000       280000
MINI Cooper                        100        23000      2300025
```

What I don't under is how these two lines are formated

```
    final String HEADING_FMT_STR = "%-25s%13s%13s%13s\n";
    final String DATA_FMT_STR =  "%-25s%13d%13.0f%13.0f\n";
```

More specifically, the parts: How is this formatted and how does it translate to making the output work?

`"%-25s%13s%13s%13s\n"`

`"%-25s%13d%13.0f%13.0f\n"`

Also I'm trying to figure out how to get commas for the values to appear in my Value column. What would I have to add to get them to show up?

Comment: [Here's the format string documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html).  [Edit] your question to explain which part you don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

The following will print commas in the Value column (notice the inclusion of the comma in the DATA_FMT_STR).

```
 final String DATA_FMT_STR =  "%-25s%13d%13.0f%,13.0f\n";
```

Output:

```
Item                          Quantity        Price        Value
-----                          -------       ------       ------
Mazda RX-8                          10        28000      280,000
MINI Cooper                        100        23000    2,300,025
```